# It is so slow when a callback function be called repeatedly in react native app

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

It will have a callback function called repeatedly to  when I start a download task. But It will be so slow that it can't give feedback when touch a button.

```
            Fileio.downloadFile(downloadData[downloadFileIndex].uri, '1.jpg',this.progressFunc.bind(this)).then((DownloadResult)=> {
                if (DownloadResult.statusCode == 200) {
                    let nextDownloadFileIndex = this.props.downloadFileIndex + 1;
                    this.props.dispatch(DOWNLOADED_A_FILE({
                        downloadFileIndex:nextDownloadFileIndex,
                        progressNum:0
                }))
                }
            }).catch((error)=> {
                console.log(error)
            })
```

This is my code and the callback function are as be folllowed

```
    progressFunc(DownloadBeginCallbackResult) {
    let progressNum = DownloadBeginCallbackResult.bytesWritten / DownloadBeginCallbackResult.contentLength;
    if(progressNum<=0.99){
        this.props.dispatch(DOWNLOADING_A_FILE({
            progressNum:progressNum,
            jobId:this.props.jobId
        }));
    }else{
        this.props.dispatch(DOWNLOADING_A_FILE({
            progressNum:0,
            jobId:this.props.jobId
        }));
    }
}
```

I mean I can't get feedback immediately when I touch button. I think that it is because I have a callback function called repeatedly. so js can't handle so many tasks;

Comment: *so carton*? I have no idea what that means. Can you [edit] to explain?

Comment: @ken White OK,I will

Comment: *It will be so carton* still doesn't make sense after your edit. I'm not sure that *carton* means the same in your language as it does in English.

Comment: @ken White oh, I am sorry about that. It maybe means that  'slow transition','bumpy scrolling','lag'. I look up the word in the dictionary

Comment: *Carton* in English means *a light box or container*. I don't think that is what you mean. :-)

Comment: @ken White I want express the mean 'slow transition','bumpy scrolling','lag'.not carton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does sound like JS thread is busy doing the request and not able to communicate back to UI thread. One thing you can try is to wrap you on press handler in an `InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => ...)`
See https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/interactionmanager.html